# JPA 2.0 Eclipse Link

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have this code

```
@Column(updatable=false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ExamType examType;
```

However, I can still change the value when I update it via merge. Why?

Comment: change the value in the database? Which is the DB?

Comment: no from my program..Mysql 5.1

Comment: I meant - the value in the database is changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. First, if you want the `examType` column to be included in `SQL UPDATE` statements, you shouldn't mark it with `updatable=false`. That being said, it appears that `updatable=false` is ignored when not used in combination with `insertable=false` but that's a bug in EclipseLink ([Bug 243301](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243301)), that's not what JPA says. Set it to `true` or remove it.

Secondly, with the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(updatable = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ExamType examType;

    ...
}
```

The following test method just runs fine with EclipseLink:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateOfEnum() {
    MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
    e.setExamType(ExamType.A);

    em.persist(e);
    em.flush();

    assertNotNull(e.getId());
    assertEquals(ExamType.A, e.getExamType());

    e.setExamType(ExamType.B);
    em.merge(e);
    em.flush();

    em.refresh(e); // to ensure we assert against value read from the db
    assertEquals(ExamType.B, e.getExamType());
}
```

Below the generated SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO ENTITYWITHENUM (ID, EXAMTYPE) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [1, A]
UPDATE ENTITYWITHENUM SET EXAMTYPE = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [B, 1]
SELECT ID, EXAMTYPE FROM ENTITYWITHENUM WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
```

Honestly, a bug on such an elementary thing in EclipseLink is very unlikely, more than a mistake on your side if I may :)

---

**Update:** After reading the comment from the OP, I think I got the question now (which was totally unclear to be honest): the OP actually doesn't want the `examType` to be updated which is the exact opposite of my initial understanding. So the OP is actually facing [Bug 243301](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243301) (fix to be released in 2.0.2):

> EclipseLink only allows mappings to be writable or read-only. Mappings marked as both insertable=false and updatable=false will be set as read-only.

Another workaround is described in [Bug 294803](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294803) (that the previous one duplicates).

Comment: I SAID that i dont want to be updated...
IT should be fixed...
UPDATE ENTITYWITHENUM SET EXAMTYPE = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [B, 1]

should never be called...
You are telling me how to update? I dont want the value to be updated...sorry

Comment: @Parhs I'm sorry but I answered what I understood from your question. Maybe your question was not CLEAR or POORLY asked. But I think I got it now. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I amnt a native English speaker:(
Anyways... I want to make a specific collumn read only, but insertable.
Because of the bug... insertable=false and updatable=false would only work.But setting them false i wont be able to persist!!
So only these solutions come to my mind...
1)Find by id and then update manually the attached entity..
2)Create a custom update query (this seems poor to me)

Comment: @Parhs I figured that out and that's ok (that little space in "how ever" was very confusing). But there is no need to shout (*"I SAID"*), I'm just trying to help you know. No problem anyway.

Comment: Ok thank you! I think that version 2.02 is released...
I was pissedof with eclipselink..